# SQL Join returns too many rows

Tags: sql, sql-server, join

This is a continuation of the [SQL joining dilemma](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4875696/how-do-i-join-the-results-of-two-queries-in-sql-server) I had yesterday...

I have the following tables:

```
(Student)

|   ID    |  NAME   |
|  1234   |  dave   |

(Assessment)

|     ID     |    DATE    | STUDENT_ID |  TYPE  |
|     1      |  02/03/11  |    1234    | School |
|     2      |  05/03/11  |    1234    | Parent |

(Concern) 

|   ID   |  ASSESSMENT_ID  | TOPIC | LEVEL | TOPIC_NUMBER |
|    1   |         1       | apple |   3   |       1      |
|    2   |         1       | pears |   2   |       2      |
|    3   |         2       | mango |   2   |       1      |
|    4   |         2       | dates |   4   |       2      |
```

I want to create a single row which combines the assessments and concerns:

```
| StudentId | TIoC1 | TIoC2 | TIoCScore1 | TIoCScore2 | PIoC1 | PIoC2 | PIoCScore1 | PIoCScore2 |
|   1234    | apple | pears |      3     |      2     | mango | dates |      2     |       4    |
```

This is to be exported to a stats package, so the structure has to remain as is.

This is the SQL I have now:

```
SELECT a_assessment.StudentId, 
TIoC1,TIoC2,TIoCScore1,TIoCScore2,PIoC1,PIoC2,PIoCScore1,PIoCScore2
FROM
  dbo.Assessment a_assessment
  LEFT OUTER JOIN
  (
    SELECT P.StudentId, C1.Topic AS TIoC1, C2.Topic AS TIoC2, C3.Topic AS TIoC3, C4.Topic AS TIoC4,
      C1.Level AS TIoCScore1, C2.Level AS TIoCScore2, C3.Level AS TIoCScore3, C4.Level AS TIoCScore4
    FROM dbo.Assessment P
      LEFT JOIN Concern C1 ON P.Id = C1.Assessment_Id and C1.TopicNumber = 1
      LEFT JOIN Concern C2 ON P.Id = C2.Assessment_Id and C2.TopicNumber = 2
    WHERE P.Type = 'School'
  ) a_school_cons
  ON a_school_cons.StudentId = a_assessment.StudentId
  LEFT OUTER JOIN
  (
    SELECT P.StudentId, C1.Topic AS PIoC1, C2.Topic AS PIoC2
      C1.Level AS PIoCScore1, C2.Level AS PIoCScore2
    FROM dbo.Assessment P
      LEFT JOIN Concern C1 ON P.Id = C1.Assessment_Id and C1.TopicNumber = 1
      LEFT JOIN Concern C2 ON P.Id = C2.Assessment_Id and C2.TopicNumber = 2
    WHERE P.Type = 'Parent'
  ) a_parent_cons
ON a_parent_cons.StudentId = a_assessment.StudentId
```

The problem is, it returns two identical rows!

```
| StudentId | TIoC1 | TIoC2 | TIoCScore1 | TIoCScore2 | PIoC1 | PIoC2 | PIoCScore1 | PIoCScore2 |
|   1234    | apple | pears |      3     |      2     | mango | dates |      2     |       4    |
|   1234    | apple | pears |      3     |      2     | mango | dates |      2     |       4    |
```

And I can't work out how to update this to only return one - any help gratefully received!!

Thanks as always!

Comment: You could also have a look at the edited version of my answer to your original question, which you have mentioned. There may probably be no notification sent to the OP when an answer is edited so you have just missed it.

Comment: Thanks Andriy, i didn't get notified.  I'll test your grouping suggestion today - thanks for all your help!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Doesn't adding a simple `DISTINCT` work here?

Comment: YES! I've been looking at this too long - can't believe i didn't think of that - thank you so much!

Comment: Not that this looks like the most performant query, but `DISTINCT` will give you more performance headaches...

Comment: @ck This is a seldom run (< monthly) query to produce reports, so performance isn't a key requirement for me.  However, any suggestions on optimisations would be very welcome :)

Answer (score 2):

Instead of `FROM Assessment LEFT JOIN...` do `FROM Student LEFT JOIN...`.

You only need to StudentID column, but the 2 rows in Assessment are retruning you two rows.

Comment: Thanks, I'm going to include this in a refactor!